# Console code to Userscript?

Tags: javascript, userscripts, jconsole

I'm having trouble creating a userscript for a shopping page. I want to automate a click so that when I am on a page that has a grid of items, the script will select a product that matches the users input. This will go that specific's webpage where you can select quantity and color and checkout. I have a working console function that looks like this:

```
function product_click(product) {
    $(".griditem-display-name:contains("+product+")").closest("a").click();
}
product_click("Desirable here")
```

...where "Desirable here" is the name of the product. When I try to create a .js file and load as an unpacked extension for *Chrome*, nothing happens on the webpage. Should I be expecting this? Also, I tried with the *Scriptish* extension in *Firefox* and nothing happens as well. This leads me to believe that there is something wrong/incompatibility with the code and userscripts. Any input would be greatly appreciated as I am outright perplexed.
Thank you!

```
// ==UserScript==
// @id             paneler store.nike.com-f9768fbb-7d51-6244-8db2-a7f9e8827a6f@scriptish
// @name           paneler - nike test
// @version        1.0
// @namespace      
// @author        
// @description    
// @include        http://store.nike.com/*
// @include        http://store.nike.com/
// @include        http://store.nike.com
// @include        https://store.nike.com/*
// @include        https://store.nike.com/
// @include        https://store.nike.com
// @include        store.nike.com/*
// @include        store.nike.com/
// @include        store.nike.com
// @include about:blank
// ==/UserScript==


function product_click(product) {
    $(".griditem-display-name:contains("+product+")").closest("a").click();
}

product_click("Force");
```

[image]

Comment: Did you add a userscript header ? Link us the full code please.

Comment: @OlivierH Currently, I'm working on a nike webpage just for testing purposes. [Link Here](http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/n/d1u?cp=usns_twit_110213_nsw_monotones) I'll update the question with the full userscript. The code in the edited answer searches for the keyword 'Force'. This userscript is what I have for the `Scriptish` extension in `Firefox`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add escaped double quotes in your selector :

```
 $(".griditem-display-name:contains("+product+")").closest("a").click();
```

to

```
 $(".griditem-display-name:contains(\""+product+"\")").closest("a").click();
```

Don't forget to add a `run-at` entry in your userscript header :

```
// @run-at          document-end
```

Comment: Oops forgot to include the `run-at`. When adding escaped double quotes nothing happens. =/ Would forgetting these be the only problem?

Comment: You well reinstalled the userscript after having modified the code ? I tried the javascript and it works good on the website you linked.

Comment: Yes sir. I'm using Scriptish now with Firefox and have the header as shown above plus the run-at and then I just have the function and the function call and still nothing.

Comment: Nothing in your javascript console ? No errors ?  You can access it with F12 key.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+K shows nothing in the console; no errors or anything. It's almost as if my script isn't running on the webpage. But once again if I copy and paste the code into the console line and then the function call with a parameter after, it works and goes to the webpage of the product. I'm completely befuddled.

Comment: if you don't mind me asking, what did you use to test the script? I know extensions sometimes aren't the best way to use scripts.

Comment: I just tried it in console and it was OK. I just tested it as userscript on my chrome and I got some issues to. jQuery seems to be loaded after a while on the page and the document seems to be re-created or something like that. It needs further analysis.

Comment: Hmmm interesting. Maybe something like declaring the $ variable would help? Because of jQuery, would waitforkeyelements() be of any use? Thanks again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41435/discussion-between-olivierh-and-zweed4u)